# Русифицировать mysql query browser

Tags: mysql, русификация, ubuntu

Кто-нибудь знает, как русифицировать программную оболочку `mysql query browser` и `mysql administrator`?
ОС - Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: А можно вопрос, зачем? вам мало phpmyadmin? если проект не веб, то для управления базой можно поставить apache+php скачать phpmyadmin в конфиге указать куда конектиться и всё...

Comment: пхпмайадмин не совсем привычен

Comment: мммм.... может еще язык кодерский на русском сделать.. руссифицировать С++ к примеру)) Уважаемый, а техническую литературу вы как читаете?

Answer (score 2):

Никак, имхо. Локализировать ее так никто и не начал, а теперь тем более не начнут — закончились GUI Tools. Считается, что `MySQL Workbench` их полностью заменяет, хотя это не совсем правда ;). Я до сих пор держу `Query Browser` и `Administrator`, многое в них удобнее, чем в `Workbench`.

А вообще зачем? Там русифицировать особого нечего, все и так понятно — интерфейс лаконичный.

Comment: Все равно, мне привычнее как то русский видеть